# Scraping table from State of Texas Query Tool

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all of the results from this query on the Texas RRC Production Query Tool:

http://webapps2.rrc.texas.gov/EWA/productionQueryAction.do?pager.pageSize=10&pager.offset=10&methodToCall=search&searchArgs.paramValue=|1=Operator|2=01|3=2019|4=01|5=2019|8=production|9=Operator|10=13|101=Both|102=01|204=district&rrcActionMan=H4sIAAAAAAAAAMWQy07DMBBFv6ZsKkUeJ6nSxSxCgS1PwSLqwsQmsZTW0cThIfnjmTiVimi3iN31vHzvCSAEygACEC6I6rL21u0fatKV2GKYuo9GUd0uN2S9Iavi7Id5VX0_yIRXEm8-1ZA07n2RloXgvsSFvLl-KVmmk-zJ6TEevh8Nfc1_JNpxP8Od8a3TT26juo4LOY77oTe1fbNG87tAceKrGqKlkpoh6RWp3bPqRjPZxdvekPKOgkQBIUUpYB2ySeezLvDoJqyP8yAQ0pjt0vk2huAlyQa1HTzZ2v-yAQc8V4c2h1_yxl_TmaOzXMUgd6ox9APCWWKwrc7NRmCcEUEwKciyYiLFoCDLw4qrp2f-Bfw3Uvd3sqQCAAA

I have written a program that will iterate through each page to obtain all results, but when I try to actually scrape the data from the table, soup variable returns NoneType.  I am using bs4 4.6.  This is what i've tried:

```
current_url = driver.current_url
soup = BeautifulSoup(current_url,'lxml') #tried html.parser as well
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"DataGrid"})
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

I'd like to scrape the table on each page and append to a pandas dataframe afterwards.  Am I missing something obvious here for returning NoneType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  you are using Selenium, i have created a logic to scrape the table values for the given url. I have used Csv to export data table from this page. I am sure this can be converted into pandas data frame.

```
import csv

    csvFile = open('DataDetails.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    link = 'http://webapps2.rrc.texas.gov/EWA/productionQueryAction.do?pager.pageSize=10&pager.offset=10&methodToCall=search&searchArgs.paramValue=|1=Operator|2=01|3=2019|4=01|5=2019|8=production|9=Operator|10=13|101=Both|102=01|204=district&rrcActionMan=H4sIAAAAAAAAAMWQy07DMBBFv6ZsKkUeJ6nSxSxCgS1PwSLqwsQmsZTW0cThIfnjmTiVimi3iN31vHzvCSAEygACEC6I6rL21u0fatKV2GKYuo9GUd0uN2S9Iavi7Id5VX0_yIRXEm8-1ZA07n2RloXgvsSFvLl-KVmmk-zJ6TEevh8Nfc1_JNpxP8Od8a3TT26juo4LOY77oTe1fbNG87tAceKrGqKlkpoh6RWp3bPqRjPZxdvekPKOgkQBIUUpYB2ySeezLvDoJqyP8yAQ0pjt0vk2huAlyQa1HTzZ2v-yAQc8V4c2h1_yxl_TmaOzXMUgd6ox9APCWWKwrc7NRmCcEUEwKciyYiLFoCDLw4qrp2f-Bfw3Uvd3sqQCAAA'
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.get(link)

    #Finding Table Headers
    Headers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='DataGrid']//tr/td[@class='PagerBanner']/parent::tr/following::tr[1]//a")
    items = []
    for header in Headers:
        items.append(header.text)
    writer.writerow(items)


    for i in range(10): #Assuming table size is 10
        values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='DataGrid']//tr/td[@class='PagerBanner']/parent::tr/following::tr[1]/following::tr["+str(i+1)+"]/td")
        rows=[]
        for value in values:
            rows.append(value.text)
        writer.writerow(rows)#writing row values
```

**This is the output,**

Operator Name   Operator No.    Oil (BBL)   Casinghead (MCF)    GW Gas (MCF)    Condensate (BBL)

4 SWIFT SERVICE LLC 953799  0   0   0   0

94 OPERATING, LP    966260  0   0   0   0

A & C OIL COMPANY, LLC  214 329 0   0   0

A. N. MAC DIARMID CO.   572 108 0   0   0

AAA OIL COMPANY 148 25  1   0   0

AARONMARK SERVICES, LLC 891 38  0   0   0

AB RESERVE, LLC 893 0   0   0   0

ABACO OPERATING, LLC    894 0   0   4,370   83

ABRAXAS PETROLEUM CORPORATION   3125    9,356   10,706  0   0

ACCORD GR ENERGY INC    3422    0   0   0   0

Comment: Thank you @Sureshmani , this was helpful! Unfortunately, scraper it this way proved to be too slow, as I need to iterate over thousands of pages.  I am opting to download the csv that is present on the page. However, your code was helpful in understanding how to scrape a html table and write the subsequent rows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a user agent and it worked. I'm not sure what you're using to make the request to the page, so I will assume you are using `requests` (because selenium or another web browser simulation is not necessary, a simple request does the trick). If so, in your request add the following parameter:

`headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36'}`

EDIT:
With selenium, you can just pass the page source code to Beautifulsoup. Your mistake right now is that you are passing the url to beautifulsoup, not the actual html.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    'http://webapps2.rrc.texas.gov/EWA/productionQueryAction.do?pager.pageSize=10&pager.offset=10&methodToCall=search&searchArgs.paramValue=|1=Operator|2=01|3=2019|4=01|5=2019|8=production|9=Operator|10=13|101=Both|102=01|204=district&rrcActionMan=H4sIAAAAAAAAAMWQy07DMBBFv6ZsKkUeJ6nSxSxCgS1PwSLqwsQmsZTW0cThIfnjmTiVimi3iN31vHzvCSAEygACEC6I6rL21u0fatKV2GKYuo9GUd0uN2S9Iavi7Id5VX0_yIRXEm8-1ZA07n2RloXgvsSFvLl-KVmmk-zJ6TEevh8Nfc1_JNpxP8Od8a3TT26juo4LOY77oTe1fbNG87tAceKrGqKlkpoh6RWp3bPqRjPZxdvekPKOgkQBIUUpYB2ySeezLvDoJqyP8yAQ0pjt0vk2huAlyQa1HTzZ2v-yAQc8V4c2h1_yxl_TmaOzXMUgd6ox9APCWWKwrc7NRmCcEUEwKciyYiLFoCDLw4qrp2f-Bfw3Uvd3sqQCAAA')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup)
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "DataGrid"})
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response.  I do need to use Selenium because I need to set the query, which involves clicking to change various parameters.  So on that note, i am not using request because when the query is set, a rather unique and long url is generated based on the query parameters

Comment: No problem. Glad to help